# FOSUserBundle - login and registration form on one page

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to make simple website, where on the main page, I will see login and register forms.
I've been thinking about this for many hours and I'm still lost. Here is my proposed design for this:

```
{# Login form #}
<div>
  {% render url('login_form') %}
</div>
<b>or</b>
{# Register form #}
<div>
  {% render url('register_form') %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOS user bundle does not support such structure (login and registration in single template) out of the box, so maybe if you want to keep things simple, then you should separate both pages.

If this structure is strongly required, then you should probably extend corresponding controllers from FOS user bundle and make them use same template for output rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make login and register in same page (at root /login) using symfony 2.8 and This is how it works for me:

First simple edit in friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Controller/SecurityController.php

at the buttom of function loginAction and befor return add this :

```
$formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
$form = $formFactory->createForm();
```

and then add the registration form view to the return to be like this:

```
return $this->renderLogin(array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
            'register_form' => $form->createView()
        ));
```

Then in your login.html.twig put where ever you want:

```
{{ form_rest(register_form) }}
```

- Important: this is will works fine for login, but in case of registration verification error it will redirect to /register !

Answer (score 0):

The only way I did achieve that feature is deactivating the csrf protection, that was only for development purposes, I strongly recommend you not to do that in a production environment, the issue behind this task is a common mistake called `CSRF Token Mismatch`, that means you are sending a token that does not correspond to that form. You can always change the login/registration form and build it using AJAX, but once again, forget about CSRF, instead you should protect with HTTPS or something like that, but you still lose a protection layer. Cheers!.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, No need for custom controllers and actions

Override default FOSUserbundle views `register.html.twig` and `login.html.twig`

**Overriden login.html.twig**

```
{% include "@FOSUser/Registration/register_content.html.twig" %}
```

**Overriden register.html.twig**

```
{% include "@FOSUser/Registration/register_content.html.twig" %}
```

**Place above two files in the following locations**

**Symfony 4**

`templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle/Security/login.html.twig`

`templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle/Security/login.html.twig`

**Symfony 3**

`app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/Security/login.html.twig`

`app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/Security/login.html.twig`

Finally, you are ready to render login and registration view on the same page, multiple pages, all pages wherever you want :P

**my_login_and_registration_page.html.twig**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {{ render(controller('fos_user.security.controller:loginAction')) }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {{ render(controller('fos_user.registration.controller:registerAction')) }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Since overridden views are no more extending FOSUserbundle base layout. You need to manage displaying of errors/messages in your layout.

**Check this file for reference:** `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig`